My function does not work, the code, separately, does
I try to create a function that checks the data frame to detect the binary vectors (columns) and changes these binary vectors into factors. I have managed to design a code. However, when I tried to wrap it into a function, the function did not work. My question is: what is wrong with my function, and what is missing?
data(mtcars)
df=mtcars
Col_Name=c()#creating an empty vector
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  if (is.numeric(df[,i])){
    Col_Name[i] <- colnames(df)[i]
  }  #checking the columns and collecting the numeric columns into a vector
  }
Col_Name <- na.omit(Col_Name)#removing the NA
for (col in 1:length(Col_Name)) {
  bi=unique(df[,col])#detecting the unique variables.
  if (is.numeric(bi)) {
    bi2=all(bi%in%c(0,1))#cheking if the unique variable contains 0 and 1
    if (bi2==TRUE) df[,col] <- as.factor(df[,col])#changing the column into a factor
  }
  
}#the function is supposed to return nothing. however when checking the data frame, 0,1 columns change into factor.
str(df)#check the impact of the code.

Now, let's wrap the code into a function.
My_binary=function(df){Col_Name=c()
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  if (is.numeric(df[,i])){
    Col_Name[i] <- colnames(df)[i]
  }  
  }
Col_Name <- na.omit(Col_Name)
for (col in 1:length(Col_Name)) {
  bi=unique(df[,col])
  if (is.numeric(bi)) {
    bi2=all(bi%in%c(0,1))
    if (bi2==TRUE) df[,col] <- as.factor(df[,col])
  }
  
}}
str(df) #return nothing>>>>

I have tried to run the function, but it returned nothing. I understand that something is missing. However, I can't figure out what.

Your function is missing return(something) at the end... assuming you call it using df <- My_binary(df), then it should say return(df) at the end of the function.

Please be careful to show the code you're actually running - the sample you gave actually shows the original set of data if we run it, not 'nothing'.

The other answer (Jilber Urbina) correct the OP code but I think that function is over complicating things.
Here is a much simpler version of the function.
my_binary <- function(df) {
  i <- sapply(df, \(x) all(x %in% 0:1))
  df[i] <- lapply(df[i], factor)
  df
}

my_binary(mtcars) |> str()
#> 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  11 variables:
#>  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>  $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>  $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>  $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>  $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>  $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>  $ vs  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
#>  $ am  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>  $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...

Created on 2024-05-27 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you for your simplifications. However, It was a little practice to combine more than one function and skill such as loops and conditioning to create a function. Thank you for your suggestion. Much appreciated.

You need to add return(df) right before the last }. Doing so, your output is:
> str(My_binary(mtcars))
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ am  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...


Here is the corrected version of your code. Your function was not returning any value
df_mtcars <- mtcars

my_binary <- function(df){
  Col_Name=c()
  for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
    if (is.numeric(df[,i])){
      Col_Name[i] <- colnames(df)[i]
    }  
  }
  Col_Name <- na.omit(Col_Name)
  for (col in 1:length(Col_Name)) {
    bi=unique(df[,col])
    if (is.numeric(bi)) {
      bi2=all(bi%in%c(0,1))
      if (bi2==TRUE) df[,col] <- as.factor(df[,col])
    }
    df2 = df
  }
  
  return(df2)
}

str(my_binary(df_mtcars))


'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ am  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...

I hope this helps!

thank you for your help. It works. It seems I should not neglect the return() function.
